# Design requires heading text to break into boostrap responsive column with background

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, css

I'm using a grid of rectangles to display content on a boostrap 3 responsive grid.

I need text to be like in the orange area in the mockup below (where it says category):

[image]

This represents one rectangle within a grid of other rectangles.

I also need a heading bottom right (secondary question).

I don't even know what to search for in Google - I tried a few things that returned nothing.

It steps both into the padding / margin / column of the grid.

Is this possible in a bootstrap 3 grid?

I need this to work in at least 99% of installed browsers. Ideally it will look the same on mobile responsive width too (just with the usual single column).

Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried limiting the width of the element? The text should break automatically.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I quickly designed this using [this](https://startbootstrap.com/template-overviews/thumbnail-gallery/) template for the gallery.

I wrote 3 classes, a heading, category and triangle class:

```
.heading {
  display: inline-block;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  padding: 5px;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 30px;
  right: 35px;
  color: white;
}

.category {
  display: inline-block;
  background-color: #ff9800;
  padding: 5px;
  position: absolute;
  left: 5px;
  color: white;
}
.triangle {
  position: absolute;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 0 10px 16px 0;
  border-color: transparent #e65100 transparent transparent;
  left:5px;
  top: 55px;
}
```

---

If you want to see the source of the whole website just click [here](http://use1ess.bplaced.net/stack/niico/)

---

Desktop view:
[image: Desktop view]

Mobile view:
[image: Mobile view]